# ID3 tag in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, filestream, id3

Can someone tell me what's wrong with the following code?

```
    Dim mp As FileStream
    Dim Title(30) As Byte
    mp = New FileStream(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyMusic & "\Set List Planner\Tracks" & filename, FileMode.Open)
    mp.Seek(-125, SeekOrigin.End)
    mp.Read(Title, 0, 30)

    Me.songName = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Title)
```

On line 4 I keep getting:

> An attempt was made to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that your file is less than 125 bytes long. You are trying to move your stream position 125 bytes before your End of File. I would check for the [`Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.length.aspx) of the file before trying to move your stream position.  Such as:

```
Dim mp As FileStream
Dim Title(30) As Byte
mp = New FileStream(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyMusic & "\Set List Planner\Tracks" & filename, FileMode.Open)
If mp.Length >= 125 Then
    mp.Seek(-125, SeekOrigin.End)
    mp.Read(Title, 0, 30)
    Me.songName = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Title)
End If
```

---

Just for an aside I tried your code using a sample Mp3 just to make sure I was not being flippant, it did extract the title of the song. I would reiterate that you need to verify the length of your stream before doing your Seek. For instance the length of the song that I used was 8414449.

Answer (score 2):

You really should look into using TagLib# to read and write ID3 tags. Then it is as easy as:

```
Dim _MP3FilePath As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyMusic & "\Set List Planner\Tracks" & filename
Dim _MP3File As TagLib.File = TagLib.File.Create(_MP3FilePath)
Me.songname = _MP3File.Tag.Title
```

To reference the taglib sharp library you must first install it via NuGet. To install TagLib#, run the following command in the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio.

```
PM> Install-Package taglib
```

The NuGet distribution of taglib-sharp can be found at http://nuget.org/packages/taglib. The official source code repository is at https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp.